# how to develop map application in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I want to develop map application, where I can find places from application. I am new in android. I want some starting direction and suggestions.
Graceful to any which can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a map application you can use as well Google maps for android. For this you can check this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 . I advise you to do this tutorial and you will understand how everything works so you can make eventually your own application.

You can refer to Google maps android API as well from the developer.android site: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

As you can see the first link is about API2 and maybe you wonder why not API3 if already is public. The answer is simple: API3 -> Javascript. If you are a starter you better start with something easier, but I will post the links necessary here as well.

**Google Maps *Javascript* API v3** is javascript based and an example of implementation for mobile is here -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Mobile

For full documentation on **Google Maps *Javascript* API v3**, follow this link -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial